# How to use DisclosureGroup as Dropdown in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to use the DisclosureGroup as dropdown and let the user to choose and display the option on textbox. I've stored my array in my model and retrieving the data.

This is my arrays in model

```
var newContents: [String] = ["Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "White"]
```

This is the code I used for DisclosureGroup

```
 HStack{
            Text("Select : ")
            DisclosureGroup("\(MyViewModel.MyModel.newContents[0])", isExpanded: $isScollExpanded){
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8){
                          ForEach(MyViewModel.MyModel. newContents, id: \.self){ index in
                              Text("\(index)")
                                  .onTapGesture {
                                  self.MyViewModel.MyModel.newContents[0] = index
                                  withAnimation{
                                   self.isScollExpanded.toggle()
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }.padding()
                                   }
                                }
            
                               }
```

This code works like, when I choose an option it repeats for twice and 1st string from the array is missing. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead or changing the first item, you can have a variable for `selection`. Change the `DisclosureGroup` title and change the `selection` when tapped, as shown below. The data is not mutated anymore, just the selection is what changes.

The following solves your problem:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selection = "Yellow"
    private let newContents: [String] = ["Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "White"]
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isScrollExpanded = false
    //
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Select : ")
            DisclosureGroup(MyViewModel.MyModel.selection, isExpanded: isScrollExpanded) {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                        ForEach(MyViewModel.MyModel.newContents, id: \.self) { str in
                            Text("\(str)")
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    MyViewModel.MyModel.selection = str
                                    withAnimation{
                                        isScrollExpanded.toggle()
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much the answer. but I want to get this array and selection from my model. can you please help me to achieve that?

Comment: @gamedi3060 It's a bit unclear what you mean. You can get `newContents` from your model, I just did it like this so I could run it as I don't have your `MyViewModel` and stuff code. You could also store `selection` there if you want, too.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I got the concept and it fixed everything!

Comment: @gamedi3060 Edited it now, should hopefully make more sense. Glad it works now!